# Address certain core for threads in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a list of 40 files, which I want to modify through my script.
Since every file processed in the same way, I want to use Threads to speed it up.
Therefore I have this construct :

```
my $threads_ = sub 
{
     while (defined(my $taskRef = $q->dequeue())) 
     {                
         my $work= shift(@{$workRef});
         &{\&{$work}}(@{$workRef});
         my $open= $q->open() - 1;
     }
};

my @Working;
for( my $i = 1; $i < 8; $i++)
{
     push @Working, threads->new($threads_);
}
```

And I have this code for starting a thread for every file

```
foreach my $File (@Filelist)
{
    $q->enqueue(['mySub',$FirstVar,$SecondVar]);
}
```

But it still takes way to long time.

My question is, is there a certain way to assign each thread to a single Core, in order to speed it up?

Comment: Check your IO performance first (slow disk?)

Comment: just checked it again with `sar` , and %iowait is 0.22, so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: You can take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/MCE Btw, how did you check how many cores are in use by perl?

Comment: @Сухой27 Related: [Can Parallel::ForkManager speed up a seemingly IO bound task?](http://www.nu42.com/2012/04/can-parallelforkmanager-speed-up.html). With disk caches, it is sometimes possible to gain a speed advantage this way. Perl's threads may not be the best way to take advantage of extra cores, but I don't have time to test it. However, it is not too difficult to check with [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) if process level parallelism yields better results.

Comment: @SinanÜnür That's why I've suggested to check IO. Btw OP wants to read and modify files, and if I'm not mistaken your example only read the files.

Comment: I don't _think_ you can set core affinity with threads. But I'm also not really sure it'll help much. OS schedulers are pretty good, and you'll probably accomplish about as much with `renice`. I would suggest though that looking at what you're doing with the subroutines might yield better fruit. (Like, it looks like you're passing symbolic references around, and that makes me a little twitchy)

Comment: @Sobrique I have already checked most of the subroutines and there is not much left to optimize beside getting better performance by the threads

Comment: Have you run it through a profiler yet?  That.way you could see where you are spending your runtime.

Comment: @Sobrique Yes, most time is spend at processing the lines, but there are no options to shorten it. it takes about half a second to process one line, but there are several thousand lines per file.

Comment: Half a second per line sounds like a lot. *shrug*. You can probably fork and set affinity, but I don't honestly think context switches will be slowing you down significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Parallel::ForkManager for something like this; it works great.  I'd recommend not brewing your own when an accepted standard solution exists.  By "address certain core", I take it to mean your purpose is to limit the number of concurrent tasks to the number of available processors and ForkManager will do this for you -- just set the max number of processes when you initialize your ForkManager object.

The commenters above were absolutely correct to point out that I/O will eventually limit your throughput, but it's easy enough to determine when adding more processes fails to speed things up.

Comment: The limitation of current tasks is done by the lower for-loop. There I start a maximum of 8 threads. What i wanted to archieve is Thread 1 -> Core 1, Thread 2-> Core 2 and so on.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  Such would be managed by the OS and I have never heard of such low-level control in any language.